# Select from Service Based Database not finding any values without a selection in a DataGridView (WinFormsApp VB .Net Framework)

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I'm quite new to VB .Net and Databases in general so I'm not sure which SQL Version I am using. I did most of my coding until now with VBA.

I added a "Service Based Database" to my "WinFormsApp" Project and created a Table with 3 Columns:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[employees] (
    [id]   INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [nr]   VARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [name] TEXT          NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id] ASC)
);
```

Afterwards I added a Dataset for the created Table.

Following this, I added a new Form to my Project and added a few controls to it including two TextBoxes for Dataentry and a DataGridView to show the saved data. On Form_Load I fill the DataGridView using the following code:

```
    Private Sub UpdateGridView()

        'Loading the data into the GridView
        '---------------------------------------
        Dim Conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection
        Dim ADP As SqlDataAdapter
        Dim DS As DataSet = New DataSet

        Conn.ConnectionString = My.Settings.DBConnEmployees
        ADP = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM employees", Conn)
        ADP.Fill(DS)

        Me.DataGridView_Employees.DataSource = DS.Tables(0)
        '---------------------------------------

        'Hidding the ID Col
        Me.DataGridView_Employees.Columns(0).Visible = False

    End Sub
```

Also in the Form_Load I set a few unrelated variables and TextBoxes (as I'm not able to find the errors after several hour of trial and error, I include this. Maybe I'm overlooking something):

```
    Private Sub NewEmployee()

        'Reseting the Variables
        DataGridIndex = -1
        EmployeeId = 0
        EmployeeNr = String.Empty
        EmployeeName = String.Empty

        'Writing to TBs
        Me.tbNr.Text = EmployeeNr
        Me.tbName.Text = EmployeeName

        'Select Nothing
        Me.DataGridView_Employees.CurrentCell = Nothing

        'Changing Btn Desc
        Me.btnSaveEmployee.Text = "Neuen Mitarbeiter speichern"

    End Sub
```

The testing data I entered into the table by hand fills in without a problem. Inserting, updating an deleting into/from the table by code works perfect.

On DataGrivView_CellDoubleClick I read some data of the the GridView into the TextBoxes to edit them:

```
    Private Sub DataGridView_Employees_CellDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView_Employees.CellDoubleClick
        If e.RowIndex <> -1 Then

            'Loading selected Data
            DataGridIndex = e.RowIndex
            EmployeeId = Me.DataGridView_Employees.Rows(DataGridIndex).Cells(0).Value
            EmployeeNr = Me.DataGridView_Employees.Rows(DataGridIndex).Cells(1).Value
            EmployeeName = Me.DataGridView_Employees.Rows(DataGridIndex).Cells(2).Value

            'Write to TBs
            Me.tbNr.Text = EmployeeNr
            Me.tbName.Text = EmployeeName


            'Changing btn
            Me.btnSaveEmployee.Text = "Änderungen speichern"

        End If
    End Sub
```

To prevent the User from using the nr twice I wanted to check if the nr is already saved in the Table. However this is where the problems begin. The SQLCommand only finds the row which i double clicked in the GridView. Which is strange as there should be no connection between them. Hereafter my try at checking for the nr:

```
    Private Function EmployeeNrInUse(id As Integer, nr As String) As Boolean

        Dim Query As String = String.Empty
        Dim Result
        Dim Response As Boolean = True

        'Checking for nr
        '---------------------------------------
        Query = "SELECT * FROM employees WHERE nr=@nr"

        Using Conn = New SqlConnection(My.Settings.DBConnEmployees)
            Using Comm = New SqlCommand()
                With Comm
                    .Connection = Conn
                    .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    .CommandText = Query
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@nr", nr)
                End With
                Try
                    Conn.Open()
                    Result = Comm.ExecuteScalar
                    Response = Not IsNothing(Result)
                Catch ex As SqlException
                    MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString, vbOKOnly + vbCritical)
                End Try
            End Using
        End Using
        '---------------------------------------

        'Return
        Return Response

    End Function
```

The Result is always returning nothing, unless I double clicked a dataentry before, then it finds it's own row (if the nr matches) but only that, no other matching nr is found.

If I forgot to mention crucial data, please inform me as this is my first question ever in a forum :) (Also please excuse any spelling mistakes etc. as English isn't my native language) Thanks in Advance for your help!

*Edit:*
This is how the Function EmployeeNrInUse is called (Called on Button_Clicked):

```
    Private Sub SaveEmployeeToDB(id As Integer, nr As String, name As String)

        Dim Query As String = String.Empty

        'Adding new Employee / Editing existing
        '---------------------------------------

        If EmployeeNrInUse(id, nr) Then
            MsgBox("Nr. bereits in verwendung.", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation)
            Exit Sub
        End If

        If EmployeeId = 0 Then
            Query = "INSERT INTO employees (nr, name) VALUES (@nr, @name)"
        Else
            Query = "UPDATE employees SET nr=@nr, name=@name WHERE id=@id"
        End If

        Using Conn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.DBConnEmployees)
            Using Comm As New SqlCommand()
                With Comm
                    .Connection = Conn
                    .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    .CommandText = Query
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id) 'Wird nur bei änderung verwendet
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@nr", nr)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name)
                End With

                Try
                    Conn.Open()
                    Comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    UpdateGridView()
                    If EmployeeId = 0 Then
                        MsgBox("Neuen Mitarbeiter gespeichert.", vbOKOnly + vbInformation)
                    Else
                        MsgBox("Bestehenden Mitarbeiter aktualisiert.", vbOKOnly + vbInformation)
                    End If
                    NewEmployee()
                Catch ex As SqlException
                    MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString, vbOKOnly + vbCritical)
                End Try
            End Using
        End Using
        '---------------------------------------

    End Sub
```

Comment: Can you show the code of how your function `EmployeeNrInUse` is being called?

Comment: @TimothyG. I've added it to my question.

Comment: One thing it could be is that [`ExecuteScalar`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0#returns) returns "The first column of the first row in the result set, or a null reference (Nothing in Visual Basic) if the result set is empty".  Since you are performing a `SELECT *`, the first column coming back will be the first column in your table.  You should explicitly state what column you want to come back in your `ExecuteScalar` command - I can't tell what your first column coming back is, but I wonder if its null/wrong

Comment: `[name] TEXT  NULL,` NO NO NO NO NO! This datatype has been deprecated for almost 20 years; varchar(max) is the appropriate replacement type. But no name is that long and I doubt column NR should be varchar(max) either. And at least one of those columns should not be nullable (likely both). If NR should be unique, then let the db engine handle that.

Comment: And don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Comment: @TimothyG. I've changed it to Select the id but unfortunatly that didn't work either.

Comment: @SMor I've replaced Text by varChar and also chose a suitable length instead of max. As I'm a total beginner, I don't know how to make the db enginge handle the nr as unique, could you explain me how? However I don't think this would solve the problem as the action should be preventet before trying to save it to the db so the User can change it before it gets a problem.

Could you explain me the problem with AddWithValue, and what would be the alternative?

Comment: I think I found the issue. The DataBase stores the values with an attached vbCrlf. So everytime I searched for just the nr, there would be no match. But if I just fill in the TextBox from the GridView then it copys the vbCrlf with it and is able to find itself. Does someone know how the prevent the vbCrlf in my DataBase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by entering the values into the Database by hand. While copying the nr, a linebreak sneaked itself into the values so a check just for the nr instead the nr and the linebreak resulted in nothing. Properly entering the data has fixed the problem.